# How to convert datatable to list<> or array?

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I want to get all the data from a table using the code below:

```
            CameraBUS cameraBus = new CameraBUS();   //Contain class provider access to DAO for GetByAllCamera.

            DataTable dt = cameraBus.Camera_GetByAllCamera();   //select * from table Camera

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                CameraDTO camera = new CameraDTO(row);
                if(camera.IDKhuVuc == 4)
                {
                    OpenCamera(camera.ViTri, camera.TaiKhoan, camera.MatKhau, camera.IP);     
                }

                if(camera.IDKhuVuc == 3)
                {
                    OpenCamera(camera.ViTri, camera.TaiKhoan, camera.MatKhau, camera.IP);
                }
            }
```

If camera.IDKhuVuc have 7 rows or more. It's always start StartThead1 and my program stop not working.
Example:

My data has 4 rows, but this code can't get 4 rows of 4 cameras. It only opens the first and last cameras.

When I debug my program, it runs 2 rows (rows 2, 3). But when I run my program, it's not opening camera 2 and camera 3.

I think I should use List<> or array. How could I fix this?

Class `OpenCamera()`:

```
        private void OpenCamera(bool position, string username, string password, string ipAddress)
        {
            if (!position)
            {
                axLiveX1.IpAddress = ipAddress;
                axLiveX1.UserName = username;
                axLiveX1.Password = password;
                axLiveX1.DataPort = 5550;
                axLiveX1.CommandPort = 4550;
                axLiveX1.AudioDataPort = 6550;
                axLiveX1.DefaultCam = 8;
                axLiveX1.OnGetPicture += new AxLIVEXLib._DLiveXEvents_OnGetPictureEventHandler(axLiveX1_OnGetPicture);
                axLiveX1.AutoLogin = true;
                if (axLiveX1.Connect())
                {

                }
                axLiveX1.StartGrapImage(true);

                axLiveX2.IpAddress = ipAddress;
                axLiveX2.UserName = username;
                axLiveX2.Password = password;
                axLiveX2.DataPort = 5550;
                axLiveX2.CommandPort = 4550;
                axLiveX2.AudioDataPort = 6550;
                axLiveX2.DefaultCam = 8;
                axLiveX2.OnGetPicture += new AxLIVEXLib._DLiveXEvents_OnGetPictureEventHandler(axLiveX2_OnGetPicture);
                axLiveX2.AutoLogin = true;
                axLiveX2.Connect();
                axLiveX2.StartGrapImage(true);
            }
            else
            {
                axLiveX3.IpAddress = ipAddress;
                axLiveX3.UserName = username;
                axLiveX3.Password = password;
                axLiveX3.DataPort = 5550;
                axLiveX3.CommandPort = 4550;
                axLiveX3.AudioDataPort = 6550;
                axLiveX3.DefaultCam = 8;
                axLiveX3.OnGetPicture += new AxLIVEXLib._DLiveXEvents_OnGetPictureEventHandler(axLiveX3_OnGetPicture);
                axLiveX3.AutoLogin = true;
                axLiveX3.Connect();
                axLiveX3.StartGrapImage(true);

                axLiveX4.IpAddress = ipAddress;
                axLiveX4.UserName = username;
                axLiveX4.Password = password;
                axLiveX4.DataPort = 5550;
                axLiveX4.CommandPort = 4550;
                axLiveX4.AudioDataPort = 6550;
                axLiveX4.DefaultCam = 8;
                axLiveX4.OnGetPicture += new AxLIVEXLib._DLiveXEvents_OnGetPictureEventHandler(axLiveX4_OnGetPicture);
                axLiveX4.AutoLogin = true;
                axLiveX4.Connect();
                axLiveX4.StartGrapImage(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col A", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col B", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col C", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, 20, 30 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 100, 200, 300 });

            List<DataRow> rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).ToList();
            var numbers = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();

        }
    }
}
​
​
```

You can get data of any cell like this with your original code

```
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string colA = (string)row["Col A"];
            }​
```

To Get entire column try something like this

```
           var colA = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Col A")).ToList();​
```

Comment: Thanks. If I using list like this. How to get values of 1 rows or 1 columns?

I debug an `dt` variables hold all values in table.

I edit my code:

http://pastebin.com/dy7vtVdn

I don't know get value to execute if statement.

Thank you very much

Comment: That good. I don't know use class `OpenCamera` with parameter. You can see my problem here.

http://pastebin.com/bwZcmeyC

Comment: GetOnePicture should not be in the OpenCamera() method.  You need another method to get a single picture. that returns the image.  Your OpenCamera() has no return parameter (void).

Comment: Ok. Should OpenCamera() class return values? Bool or Int?

And in condition, how to call if(x.x == ?) to action OpenCamera()?

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing in the OpenCamera() method has any error condition that can be returned.  I would add an exception handler so when an exception occurs an error condition would be returned.  I also assume the connect method returns an value when the open fails.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Can you demo code? I must transmit values to `OpenCamera()` so open it from Main form. Main form contain control AxLiveXx to open camera and it's require any values

Comment: Don't have any documentation on the AxLiveXx control.

Comment: This control of Camera. Here is SDK.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vv7rxb5jdxygo3v/SDKHelp.chm?dl=0)
I want read 1 rows in database, then check condition. If condition is true, it will run function OpenCamera(). Problem is when have many rows it must check many OpenCamera. I don't want. I want when condition success, I group all rows and open all camera.

Comment: Only got top layer of webpage.  Just index with no contents.  Have to save as flat file or zip the entire folder(s).

Comment: [Here sdk install](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6bkr3wo13rhlbg/SDK.rar?dl=0)
Thank you @jdweng